# WEIRD "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Tags: python, parsing, python-requests, instagram-api

**The problem:** when i try to use the first code below, i got `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. All that code worked fine yesterday and also yesterday it stopped working. Today it's not working too. The strange part that i just launched second code (also below) and it worked once and then after another launch it got the same problem again!

The error is thrown by the line:

```
post_info = instagram_web_api.media_info2("<SHORTCODE>")
```

Please, help : (. Russian stack overflow has no answers.

I use [`instagram-private-api 1.6.0.0`](https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api)

**1-st code** when i get that error:

```
from instagram_web_api import Client

instagram_web_api = Client(auto_patch=False, drop_incompat_keys=False)

post_info = instagram_web_api.media_info2('CVNgb7us34V') # Get the short code.
post_text = post_info['edge_media_to_caption']['edges'][0]['node']['text']

print(post_text)
```

**2-nd code:**

```
from instagram_web_api import Client

web_api = Client(auto_patch=False, drop_incompat_keys=False)
user_feed_info = web_api.user_feed('329452045', count=10)
```

[image]

Comment: Examine what you’re trying to decode that your code is assuming is JSON, because the error is saying that it _isn’t_ JSON.

Comment: @balmy, I think that is right JSON, because the short code for the post  i took from the actual URL of the post (and tried many different posts) and second because this code worked perfectly nice yesterday.

Comment: @2e0byo, sorry, what do you mean? I can't print "post_info" because that problem appears before "post_info" gets data.

Comment: Forget about yesterday, your code is failing today. If it were receiving JSON it wouldn’t give that error, ergo it’s not receiving JSON. Look at what you’re getting because it’s probably HTML with information which will help you understand what’s going on.

Comment: @balmy, i don't understand where to look, i looked in HTML structure of the post and i don't know what i should find there. : ( Please help

Comment: I've edited the q to show where the error is being thrown.  As @balmy says, you're likely getting a useful response from the server.  I don't know what `instagram_web_api` *is*, and google was less than helpful.  Can you *edit the question* and add a link to the library?  You're going to need to intercept the html response yourself, since the high-level function you're using here is simply failing without telling you what you *are* getting

Comment: @2e0byo, i added a name of the library and here is also a link to pypi https://pypi.org/project/instagram-private-api/

Comment: @2e0byo, i don't know how to intercept the html response at all...

Comment: @balmy, but why did i launch 2-nd code and it worked for once, but then another launch and it's failed?? It is strange

Comment: Added a photo of errors in CMD

Comment: Perhaps the website blocked you. Clearly your code worked before, so why could it be any other problem than the response being unexpectedly wrong/not JSON. On Windows you can use a proxy like Telerik Fiddler classic to examine the http messages going to/fro. On linux us mitm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is between the library you are using and instagram: the latter is not sending you JSON where you expect it.

If you have a look at [the source](https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api/blob/master/instagram_web_api/client.py#L525-L549) for `media_info2` it looks like this:

```
def media_info2(self, short_code):
    """
    Alternative method to get media info. This method works for carousel media.

    :param short_code: A media's shortcode
    :param kwargs:
    :return:
    """
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': self.user_agent,
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Connection': 'close',
        'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com',
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }
    info = self._make_request(
        'https://www.instagram.com/p/{0!s}/'.format(short_code),
        query={'__a': '1', '__b': '1'},
        headers=headers)
    ...
```

Following your traceback, the error is in `make_request`.  So we go and look at [the source](https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api/blob/master/instagram_web_api/client.py#L214-L301) and we see that the important lines are:

```
self.logger.debug('REQ DATA: {0!s}'.format(data))
res = self.opener.open(req, data=data, timeout=self.timeout)
...

if return_response:
    return res
response_content = self._read_response(res)
    self.logger.debug('RES BODY: {0!s}'.format(response_content))
    return json.loads(response_content)
```

We now have everything we would need to do a bit of manual debugging, since the program works like this:

- set headers and pass them and url to make_request
- get data from url
- parse date as json
- return data

We *could* put together our own call to `opener`, or even just run `curl` on the url passed to `_make_request`, or temporarily modify the code to print some stuff and be a bit more verbose.  But in this case we have an even easier option: the code will *already* debug itself for us, we just have to tell it to be verbose:

```
import logging
logging.basic_config(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Put that at the top of your failing script and run it again, and it should spew out lots of data telling you exactly what it's doing.  Since it prints the *entire return body*, you should get whatever it's returning, and be able to figure out what's going on.

And remember.... use the source, Luke.

Alright, that was awful, but the only way to know what code is doing is to *read the source*.  The great thing about python is its readability.  Compare this to trying to figure out some c++ library by reading it...

Comment: Oh my god you are nice!!! And big thank you for your help, i get the HTML code now with some data from Instagram, but here is not text of post and i also don't know how to use that html text, because it's written in my CMD..

Comment: look at what it says: if it's just the post, one of the assumptions in the library is broken (i.e. the method used to get json isn't working).  without digging into the library I don't know how to mend it, but you could try explicitly requesting JSON by replacing the `Accept` line with `"Accept": "application/json"`.  If you fiddle, clone `instagram-private-api` from github and put `instagram_web_api` in the same folder as your code, and modify it there.  Or open an issue on the git project if you think it *should* work (likely).  But note the number of open issues at the moment...

Comment: And i also have run 2-nd code again and it works now, but first code still doesn't work and this is crazy

Comment: sure, code which interacts with servers is at the mercy of those servers, and this is an unofficial set of bindings, so it will tend to get out of step with instagram's servers.  Sadly it's a fact of life for writing api consumers

Comment: have clarified answer: you can't (easily) *use* the debugging output: it's just to see what's happening, and what you're actually being sent.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Gonna try that and pray to god

Comment: hello!!!! I tried another library for Inst. API and it works nice! The name of API 'instagrapi'

Comment: nah, everything got broken with the same problem, but now there is something about need to sing in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because Instagram doesn't allow many requests at some time, so after i request it many times, it blocks my access to get any info from the post. The solution is to login in in API. That's all.

Comment: Now do you believe the error message, i.e. the website wasn’t providing JSON?